# Como acceder a la estructura de este resultado de Twitter?

Tags: python, json, tweepy

Poseo esta porción de código: uso (Tweepy)

```
firstTweet = api.user_timeline('twitter')[0]
print(firstTweet.text)
print(firstTweet.id)
results = api.retweets(firstTweet.id)
print(results)
```

Al obtener el resultado obtengo lo siguiente:

> [Status(possibly_sensitive=False, in_reply_to_user_id=None, contributors=None, retweeted=False, retweet_count=77, favorite_count=0, created_at=datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 2, 12, 56, 25), text='RT @twitter: Follow conversation about #iCaucused live as the results come in: https://t.co/zLFXyWi2If https://t.co/S4CL0in2Vb', place=None, lang='en', entities={'symbols': [], 'urls': [{'display_url': 'twitter.com/search?q=%23iC…', 'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/search?q=%23iCaucused%20&src=typd', 'url': 'https://t.co/zLFXyWi2If', 'indices': [79, 102]}, {'display_url': 'twitter.com/gov/status/694…', 'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/gov/status/694324978859274240', 'url': 'https://t.co/S4CL0in2Vb', 'indices': [103, 126]}], 'user_mentions': [{'id_str': '783214', 'screen_name': 'twitter', 'id': 783214, 'name': 'Twitter', 'indices': [3, 11]}], 'hashtags': [{'text': 'iCaucused', 'indices': [39, 49]}]}, user=User(profile_image_url='http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/690229058941091840/ddrGbH4l_normal.jpg', is_translator=False, profile_banner_url='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/4833412558/1453398412', description='', contributors_enabled=False, screen_name='abdulazeeznima2', profile_image_url_https='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/69 .....

Corto por cuestiones de espacio...

Estoy obteniendo información de quién ha hecho RT (o quiénes).... ahora ¿cómo accedo a cada uno de los items ?

Ejemplo:
¿Quién dio RT ?
¿Cuál es su `screen_name` ?
¿Tiene `GEO` activado ?

¡Gracias a todos!

Otra pregunta... ¿por qué ese `json` (si lo es) está mal formado y dónde y cómo puedo formatearlo correctamente para visualizarlo de manera ordenada?

Comment: Hola, ¿estás usando `tweepy`?

Comment: Si, perdon si no lo puse, uso Tweepy, ahora corrijo el ejemplo... gracias

Comment: ahí te agregué el tag.

Comment: Muchas gracias !

Comment: @papabomay Puedes pegar tu json en http://json.parser.online.fr/beta/ Te lo va a parsear e indicar los posibles errores

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los resultados que obtienes son listas de objetos `Status`, que no es otra cosa que *wrappers* de los datos devueltos por la API de twitter. Entre los atributos del objecto `Status` tienes la información que buscas:

```
retweets = api.retweets(firstTweet.id)
users = [ tw.user for tw in retweets ]
user_names = [ user.screen_name for user in users ]
```

Los atributos de cada objeto depende únicamente de la [API de twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public); tweepy tan sólo hace un encapsulamiento de los resultados para facilitar la programación en python. Utitiliza directamente la [API de twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) si lo que quieres es procesar las respuestas en `json`.

Y, como es habitual en python, para obtener los atributos de un objeto se usa la función `dir()`.

**EDITADO:** El mecanismo de instrospección de python típico es usando la función `dir()` e ir navegando a través de los atributos de un objeto. Tweepy provee a todos sus modelos del método `.__getstate__()` para obtener el diccionario de atributos que, posiblemente, es lo que quieres.

```
>>> status.__getstate__() 
{
 'contributors': None, 
 'truncated': False, 
 'text': '....',
 'in_reply_to_status_id': None,
 'id': 21041793667694593,
 '_api': <tweepy.api.api object="" at="" 0x6bebc50="">,
 'author': <tweepy.models.user object="" at="" 0x6c16610="">,
...

>>> status.author.__getstate__()
{
....
```

De todos modos te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo al [código fuente del modelo](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/models.py) para que te aclares cómo funciona.

Todos los *modelos* derivan de la clase `Model`, que tiene un método `parse` para procesar las respuestas json. Este método convierte cada atributo de json en atributos del modelo:

```
class Status(Model):

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, api, json):
        status = cls(api)
        setattr(status, '_json', json)
        for k, v in json.items():
            if k == 'user':
                user_model = getattr(api.parser.model_factory, 'user') if api else User
                user = user_model.parse(api, v)
                setattr(status, 'author', user)
                setattr(status, 'user', user)  # DEPRECIATED
            elif k == 'created_at':
                setattr(status, k, parse_datetime(v))
            elif k == 'source':
                if '<' in v:
                    setattr(status, k, parse_html_value(v))
                    setattr(status, 'source_url', parse_a_href(v))
                else:
                    setattr(status, k, v)
                    setattr(status, 'source_url', None)
            elif k == 'retweeted_status':
                setattr(status, k, Status.parse(api, v))
            elif k == 'place':
                if v is not None:
                    setattr(status, k, Place.parse(api, v))
                else:
                    setattr(status, k, None)
            else:
                setattr(status, k, v)
        return status
```

Como se puede ver, lo primero que hace es introducir la respuesta json en el atributo `_json`, que respondería a la pregunta que hacías al respecto. Luego hay algunos atributos que tienen un procesado específico: `author/`<s>`user`</s>, `created_at`, `source`, `retweeted_status` y `place`. El resto de atributos se meten directamente como atributos del modelo. Los modelos restantes son similares. A partir de aquí espero que te sea más fácil trabajar con esta API.

Comment: LO que no termino de entender es como conocer la estructura o 'verla' de alguna manera mas humana, a esos resultados, asi puedo saber en primer lugar cual es la sintaxis correcta para acceder a esos valores y despues cual es la estructura de datos.

Comment: Como te indicaba al final de la respuesta, el mecanismo típico de *instrospección* es usando la función `dir()` e ir navegando por los atributos. El nombre exacto de los atributos lo da la API de twitter; tweepy se limita a hacer un mapeo entre los valores del resultado y los atributos del modelo. Como es algo largo de contar, lo añado a la respuesta.

Comment: Excelente explicacion, detallada, concisa, muchas gracias !